# Limit of fractional part of a function method checking

Tags: limits

Evaluate : $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}\left\{(3+2 \sqrt{2})^{n}\right\}$.    Where {} represent fractional part .

> 1 . Method : we first observe that
> {$(3+2 \sqrt{2})^{n}$} +  {$(3-2 \sqrt{2})^{n}$} = 1 , hence now take limit both sides , first assume limit of 2nd term of left side exists , then automatically 1st term would also have limit as right side already has limit of 1 . We can observe that as n goes infinity 3-2√2 approaches zero , hence limit of that 2nd part is zero ? So limit of first term is 1 ?

2. But yeah  one thing is that fractional part is not continuous when its being evaluated at x=0 so we cannot take limit inside the fractional bracket right( as fractional part is discontinuous at x=0) ? That is. $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}$ {$(3-2 \sqrt{2})^{n}$}  $\neq$
   {$ \lim _{n \rightarrow \infty}(3-2\sqrt{2})^{n}$} right ? Even though limit seems to be coming same if we consider this, but its not right right ?

Comment: I do not know if it is helpful, but $3 + 2\sqrt{2} = (1 + \sqrt{2})^{2}$.

Comment: @ÁtilaCorreia Sir i have shared my method , i would like to see whether something js incorrect or correct fully and regarding the limit of composition of fractional and exponential function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is correct (although I think you need to write more on how $\{(3+2\sqrt2)^n\}+\{3-2\sqrt2\}^n=1$ is arrived at). Regarding **2**, notice that
$$0≤(3-2\sqrt2)^n<1$$ and so we must have $$\{(3-2\sqrt2)^n\}=(3-2\sqrt2)^n$$and your limit is justified. Your point regarding discontinuity of fractional part is correct and so the above should be a part of your solution as well.

Hope this helps. :)